# When I try the run my ASP.NET Core Web API from docker, I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, docker-compose

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  microservices:
    image: "aspdotnetapp"
    container_name: api_app
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
    networks:
      - apiapp-network
    depends_on:
      - sql
  sql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: sql_server2019
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=y
      - SA_PASSWORD=/1A2b3c4d
    networks:
      - apiapp-network
networks:
  apiapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
ENV PORT=3000
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ShoppingMicroservices.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ShoppingMicroservices.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ShoppingMicroservices.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ShoppingMicroservices.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingMicroservices.dll"]
```

This is my `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ServicesDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ServicesDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True",
    "DockerDbContextConnection": "Server=sql_server2019;Database=ServicesDb;User Id=SA;Password=/1A2b3c4d;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }

}
```

Here's my code in `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ShoppingMicroservices.Controller;
using ShoppingMicroservices.Controller.Api;
using ShoppingMicroservices.Model;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ServicesDbContextConnection") ??
//throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ServicesDbContextConnection' not found.");
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DockerDbContextConnection") ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DockerDbContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExchangeRateRepository, ExchangeRateRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<InventoryController, InventoryController>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<NotificationController, NotificationController>();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ServicesDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(//builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ServicesDbContextConnectiondoc"]);
            builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DockerDbContextConnection"]);
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ServicesDbContext>();
    if (context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}

DbInitializer.Seed(app);
app.Run();
```

After I docker compose up it starts smoothly, but when I try to reach the API from `localhost:8080`, I get an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" page. I saw some things about kestrel but I didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:3000"` all i have to is just add this line into Dockerfile just before the `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingMicroservices.dll"]` line